# How to update author detail of comments in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive, google-drive-comments

I want to update the 'displayName' and 'email' of commenters within Google Sheet using 'Spreadsheet' Service along with 'Drive' service.

I have used both `Drive.comments.patch(comments, fileId, commentID)`, `Drive.comments.patch(comments, fileId, commentID)` to achieve the same, The script runs successfully but no effect within the  google sheets and doesn't change anything of comment

```
function maskComment() {
  var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var FileID =currentSpreadsheet.getId()
  var commentsList = Drive.Comments.list(FileID)

  //No effect in any of this, however the debugger lists both setDisplayName and setEmailAddress 
  commentsList.items[0].author.setDisplayName("company user"); 
  commentsList.items[0].author.setEmailAddress('test@mycompany.com');

  //No effect in any of this but code runs successfully
  Drive.Comments.patch(commentsList.items[0], FileID, commentsList.items[0].commentId) //or Drive.Comments.update(commentsList.items[0], FileID, commentsList.items[0].commentId)  No
}
```

I will appreciate any further information regarding changing  'email' and 'display name' of commenter within Google Sheets.